How do rotate my animation to my local rotation in Godot?
Right now, when I start the animation, the object goes to the rotation that the animation starts at, even if the object is rotated 180 degrees, the object goes back to the set rotation when the animation is played.
I couldn't find a ton about how to rotate the animation. I also am kinda knew to Godot and don't know how I would get around to it.

If you need to resume your animation, don't stop it, just call .pause() on it and after play it again, the same animation track will continue playing from current frame!
